# docker: what is the similar url in docker as compared to XAMMP/MAMP

Tags: codeigniter, docker

I am using docker for the codeigniter project development. Initially, when I used MAMP or XAMMP, the login page was localhost/xyz/admin/login as the server used to run on localhost (php server). But, the docker server is running on localhost:8000 and I am trying to open localhost:8000/xyz/admin/login but it shows an error that page you requested not found. Does someone know the answer to this problem? I have also tried localhost:8000/myapp_1/xyz/admin/login , localhost:8000/myapp_1/admin/login etc. but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you change the base_url in config? You need to add the PORT too in base_url like: "http://localhost:8000/xyz/"

Comment: My base_url was empty initially. No change in that.

Comment: Did you set it, as i mentioned before? Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Not sure what to set my base_url as. Previously it was nothing and the website was opening by typing localhost/xyz/admin/login. Now accordingly, it should open by localhost:8000/xyz/admin/login. But there is a new folder called myapp in the xyz folder. Not sure what is happening.

Comment: Make sure that you know the URL of your website (like localhost:8000/xyx/ or whatever). Go into application/config/config.php and add that url in $config['base_url']. That should work. If NOT, try to add a simple test.php into your web accessed root folder (where your localhost should work) and do a simple echo "hi". If that doesn't work, you need to fix the issue.

Comment: So i made a file called test.php in the folder myapp which is inside xyz. When I open localhost:8000/test.php, it works.

Comment: Ok, go to your codeigniter folder /application/config/config.php and add the http://localhost:8000/ to your $config['base_url'] IF the CI is installed in the same folder as your test.php. Otherwise add the folder too after the PORT. Also check you htaccess the RewriteBase to add the specific folder, where  your CI is installed.

Comment: Okay i solved it. I just needed to put the whole app in myapp folder. That's all. Anyway, thank you for your help :)